# How do I JOIN this one-to-many data?

Tags: sql, mysql, join

I have the following table setup:

**`t1`** has two columns: **`id`**, and **`flag_a`**.

`id` is a unique identifier, and `flag_a` is a boolean.

**`t2`** has three columns, **`id`**, and **`parent_id`**, and **`flag_b`**.

`id` is a unique identifier, `parent_id` is one of the `id`'s from `t1`, and `flag_b` is a boolean.

I need to fulfill this pseudo-query:

```
SELECT t2.id FROM t2 WHERE flag_b = 0 AND t1.flag_a = 0
```

In English: I need all of the `id`'s from `t2`, where `flag_b` is false (`0`) and where the `flag_a` belonging to the `parent_id` of `t2` is also false.

I'm familiar with the idea of using `JOIN` to accomplish this sort of thing, but I haven't much of a clue of how to actually go about doing it.

Comment: That is not a many to many relationship though...  That is one to many

Comment: Thanks Stefan. I had originally written one-, but many- seemed more correct. Fixed. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t2.id
FROM t2 INNER JOIN t1
  ON t2.parent_id=t1.id
WHERE flag_a=0 AND flab_b=0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    SELECT t2.id
      FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.Parent_id
     WHERE t1.flag_a = 0
       AND t2.flag_b = 0
```

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 1):

```
Select t2.id
From 
   t2
   INNER JOIN t1
   ON t2.parent_id = t1.ID
         and  t2.Flag_B = 0
        and t1.Flag_a = 0
```

Or

```
Select t2.id
From 
   t2
   INNER JOIN t1
   ON t2.parent_id = t1.ID

WHERE
     t2.Flag_B = 0
     and t1.Flag_a = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t2.id 
FROM t2 INNER JOIN t1 ON t2.parent_id = t1.id 
WHERE t2.flag_b = 0 AND t1.flag_a = 0
```